# Connecting to my own router via android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, tomcat, router

I work with a Tomcat server. The Tomcat server has its own remote IP. I do tests on it in my eclipse, using a local Tomcat and the local IP of 192.168.1.x. I can do tests on it via Genymotion or my browser. But my android phone doesn't know this IP, even if it sits on the router that my computer is connected to. How can my device know my local Tomcat server?

Comment: Just use IP to access (or use local DNS).

Comment: You say the phone is connected on the router as the server? So it will have the IP address around the same range and it should be possible to connect to it via some "`http://ip-address:port`" using whatever HTTP library you prefer.

Comment: The phone is not the server. The phone tries to connect to the IP 192.168.1.x but fails.

Comment: @Ran It seems to be a network question. Check network segment. (phone also has 192.168.1.y?) If not, set static ip (192.168.1.y) to the phone.

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: help:[Connect to Wi-Fi networks] https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819519?hl=en

Comment: If not using Wi-Fi, it's global address (normally). Means cannot access to local (192.168.1.x) IP.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your firewall is not blocking connections to the tomcat server